# AssetPicker Loading Via JSOM not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

here is the problem where i am able to use the object of AssetPicker to load it as a dialog box on my button click by refering the below solution

[Opening and closing AssetPortalBrowser.aspx in SharePoint modal popup](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53318/opening-and-closing-assetportalbrowser-aspx-in-sharepoint-modal-popup)
..but the issue is that when ever i clicked on "Insert" action it give the below error..
[image]

can any one have idea why ? and pls solution for it .. Urgent..

UPDATE
below is the simple code i have placed in my CEWP



    var testobj = new AssetPickerConfig();
    obj.CurrentWebBaseUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    obj.ReturnCallback = getPickertUrl;

```
function getPickertUrl(url) {
    console.log(url);
    document.getElementById('txtURL').value = url;
}

function openPicker(){
    APD_LaunchAssetPicker(testobj);
}
```

Comment: From the error its look like you are missing the callback function, i.e. `commonModalDialogClose`.

Comment: yes , but as i am not over-writing any function of AssetBrowser.aspx page ..why its breaking !!!.. it should work ..

Comment: I am not sure about why its breaking without seeing your code. But I had provided the solution below. If that was helpful, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly follow the below mentioned solution. I had test this code in IE and FireFox and its working fine there. There is also an attached demo of the same.

In my code, I am using a global variable `obj` which is not a best practice, so modify the code accordingly. Its just for the reference.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="pickerControl" width="100%" style="width:100% !important; margin-bottom: 20px" />
    <input type="button" value="Pick" onclick="openPicker()" />

</div>

<script src="/sites/test/_layouts/15/AssetPickers.js"></script>

<script>
    var obj = new AssetPickerConfig();
    obj.CurrentWebBaseUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    obj.ReturnCallback = getPickertUrl;

    function getPickertUrl(url) {
        console.log(url);
        document.getElementById('pickerControl').value = url;
    }

    function openPicker(){
        APD_LaunchAssetPicker(obj);
    }
</script>
```

**Demo**

The demo video is uploaded to my GDrive. Follow this url to check it out. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iYjISDVm-B5EjTf4G0-5IKHZnjhWbEhe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks for providing the solution , but i have the same issue even with you solution .

Comment: can you explain in details, what is your environment, and the browser version? Can you check the same functionality on different browser?

Comment: hi, i have checked in all browser but facing the same error .. not sure if it is because of any existing angular JS on my site .. but i have to implement that functionality in that environment only .. so need solution of that error ..any help will be greatly appreciated ..

Comment: Without debugging its hard to say what is causing the problem. To start with, you can open browser console (dont debug anything now), and just paste `AssetPickerConfig` into console. If it says `undefined` then there is the issue with script loading. If that works fine, now debug the function call where you had written above code. In that function in  beginning write `debugger;`, to initiate debugging and do the same thing i.e. in console paste `AssetPickerConfig`. If both works fines then angular is creating some problem. First try this and see if object is accessible or not.